# Unity 2D swipe latency on phone

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, touch, swipe

I'm trying to make a 2D infinite runner game, but the swipe isn't working properly.
There is a noticeable latency when swiping, the swipe is only happening after I stopped touching and lifted up my finger.

How can I modify the script to make swipe more responsible and to swipe while my finger is on the screen?

I hope that someone can help.

```
void Update()
{
    if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        startSwipePoz = Input.GetTouch(0).position;
    }
    if(Input.touchCount > 0 && Input.GetTouch(0).phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
    {
        endSwipePoz = Input.GetTouch(0).position;

        if (endSwipePoz.x < startSwipePoz.x && transform.position.x > -1.83f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move("left"));
        }
        if (endSwipePoz.x > startSwipePoz.x && transform.position.x < 1.83f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move("right"));

        }
    }    
}

private IEnumerator Move(string flySide)
{
    switch(flySide)
    {
        case "left":
            flyTime = 0f;
            startPoz = transform.position;
            endPoz = new Vector3(startPoz.x - 1.83f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

            while (flyTime < flyDuration)
            {
                flyTime += Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startPoz, endPoz, flyTime / flyDuration);
                yield return null;
            }
            break;

        case "right":
            flyTime = 0f;
            startPoz = transform.position;
            endPoz = new Vector3(startPoz.x + 1.83f, transform.position.y, transform.position.z);

            while (flyTime < flyDuration)
            {
                flyTime += Time.deltaTime;
                transform.position = Vector2.Lerp(startPoz, endPoz, flyTime / flyDuration);
                yield return null;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `string` parameter for defining the direction? I would suggest to rather use an `int` (1 / -1) or a `bool isRight` (true / false) or even an `enum MoveDirection { Right, Left }`! Any of these it better maintainable and less error prone than passing around and comparing `strings` :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix to your code likely looks like this (I've also moved your input read into a single .GetTouch at the beginning of your Update method, rather than calling it multiple times):

```
Touch touch;
void Update()
{
    touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
    if(Input.touchCount > 0 && touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
    {
        startSwipePoz = touch.position;
    }
    else(Input.touchCount > 0)
    {
        endSwipePoz = touch.position;

        if (endSwipePoz.x < startSwipePoz.x && transform.position.x > -1.83f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move("left"));
        }
        if (endSwipePoz.x > startSwipePoz.x && transform.position.x < 1.83f)
        {
            StartCoroutine(Move("right"));

        }
    }    
}
```

The reason your code wasn't working before was because you were waiting for TouchPhase.Ended before updating your object's position. You could alternatively add a check for TouchPhase.Moved to your code and get it working just the same.

Comment: Thank you, now the swiping is responsible, but now the player isn't going the fixed places where it should go. I updated the post and added the mover script.

Comment: The map for the game is consist of 3 lanes where the player can swipe left or right. And cars are coming from the top and the player have to avoid them, I want the player to stay in the middle of the lane

Comment: I suspect the primary issue lies in your flyDuration. That being said, you are using static values (like 1.83f, and I'm assuming flyDuration) rather than gameobjects. I would advise you to use gameobjects and transforms to achieve moving your player between positions.

For example, instead of calculating endPoz every time you swipe, have the 3 lane positions identified as transforms and "pick" which position to lerp to on swipe.